# PowerShell: Split string to key value and save those in hashtable

Tags: powershell, split, hashtable, key-value

I want to split this string `"password = 123"` into key and value and save them into a hashtable like this `$[password]="123"`

How can I do that in **PowerShell 5.1**?

Answer (score 1):

Use [-split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7) to split the string. Splitting at equals `=` will generate an array of two strings. There is whitespace, so it likely needs to be trimmed

```
$data = "password = 123" -split '='
```

Then create a hashtable and populate the key like so,

```
$ht = @{
  $data[0].trim() = $data[1].trim()
}

# Test output 1
$ht
Name                           Value
----                           -----
password                       123

# Test output 2
$ht["password"]
123
```

Comment: Ah I didn't know that split spits out an array... Thank you so much!